# Android: Fail to add a button in a custom dialog

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
chartDialog = new Dialog(item_activity.this);
                chartDialog.setContentView(R.layout.customlayout);
                chartDialog.setTitle("Title                      ");
                TextView textItemDetailsDialog = (TextView) chartDialog.findViewById(R.id.textItemDetailsDialog);
                textItemDetailsDialog.setText("Details");
                img = (ImageView) chartDialog.findViewById(R.id.ImageView001);
                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Button toMap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_toMap);
                toMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        switchTabSpecial();
                    }
                });
                chartDialog.show();
```

However, it shows

```
03-26 23:30:10.822: E/AndroidRuntime(21394): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

at line:

```
toMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Can I add a button in Dialog??
Please help...

Comment: It should be `Button toMap = (Button)chartDialogfindViewById(R.id.button_toMap);` if that button is on the dialog's layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Button is on the Dialog it should be as,

```
Button toMap = (Button)chartDialog.findViewById(R.id.button_toMap);
```